# table extracted from sql server but jquery not working

Tags: jquery, json, node.js, ajax, datatable

I am trying to display a table extracted from database(sql server) using jquery on the frontend. But it keeps on displaying the JSON format. Below is the code that I have tried till now.
Also when I execute it, it opens a download box and downloads json file. It should just open the browser and display the datatable.

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/', function (req, res) {

var sql = require("mssql");

// config for your database
var config = {
    user: 'clientinfo',
    password: 'ClientInfo123',
    server: 'USD3342',
    database: 'Client'
};
sql.close();
// connect to your database
sql.connect(config, function (err) {

    if (err) console.log(err);

    // create Request object
    var request = new sql.Request();

    // query to the database and get the records
    request.query('select * from dbo.Logs', function (err, recordset) {

        if (err) console.log(err)

        // send records as a response
        res.send(recordset);

    });
});
});

var server = app.listen(1337, function () {
console.log('Server is running..');
});
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>Error Log</title>

<script src="/server.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script 
src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "server.js/recordset",
                "method": "post",
                "dataType": "json",
                "success": function (data) {
                    $('#example').DataTable({
                        recordset: data,
                        columns: [
                            { 'data': 'Message' },
                            { 'data': 'Userid' },
                            { 'data': 'DateUTC' },
                            { 'data': 'Environment' },
                            { 'data': 'Query' },
                            { 'data': 'ShadowId' },
                            { 'data': 'StackTrace' }
                        ]
                    });
                }
            }

        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Message</th>
            <th>Userid</th>
            <th>DateUTC</th>
            <th>Environment</th>
            <th>Query</th>
            <th>ShadowId</th>
            <th>StackTrace</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

</table>
</body>

</html>
```

**package.json** (just in case)

```
{
"author": "",
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "mysql": "2.13.0",
    "tedious": "2.0.0",
    "mssql": "4.0.4"
},
"description": "",
"devDependencies": {},
"license": "ISC",
"main": "index.html",
"name": "nodejs-web-app1",
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"version": "1.0.0"
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors from node or the browser? Also, I really hope those credentials are fake; otherwise the whole world knows how to connect to your SQL Server...

Comment: Please start read and browse the [**documentation**](https://datatables.net) before you post questions on SO.  You do almost everything wrong. A few google searches will reveal hundreds of stackoverflow answers covering any aspect of the code you have above.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan well yes, the credentials are of course fake can't really make them public but there's no problem on that front. I have posted the error below:

from node I am getting SyntaxError: Unexpected token < pointing to the html tag.